# validate XML with RelaxNG in BaseX DB

Tags: basex

I want to validate XMLs against RelaxNG schema which is stored in BaseX DB.

I have also stored RelaxNG schema in DB but when I am validating it is throwing the error below.

Code for validation:

```
let $binary := db:retrieve('onix','/relaxng/publishers-51cr.rnc')
let $schema := bin:decode-string($binary)
return 
let $input := db:open('onix')
return validate:rng($input, $schema)
```

When I run the query, it throws the error:

> Invalid XML character(20)

So it is giving the error while decoding binary.

Comment: Your compact RelaxNG schema seems to contain characters that are not valid in XML 1.0.

Comment: Schema is look like :====================================================namespace a = "http://relaxng.org/ns/compatibility/annotations/1.0"
namespace ctrl = "http://nwalsh.com/xmlns/schema-control/"
default namespace db = "http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
namespace dcmitype = "http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/"
namespace dcterms = "http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
namespace mml = "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
namespace rng = "http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"

Comment: div {
  db._any.attribute =
    
    ## Any attribute, including any attribute in any namespace.
    attribute * { text }
  db._any =
    
    ## Any element from almost any namespace
    element * - (db:* | html:*) {
      (db._any.attribute | text | db._any)*
    }
}

Comment: it is not a XML i am storing the schema as a binary using function db:store in BaseX beacuse RelaxNG schema is not a XML and after that i am decoding it  as string to validate the XML.

Comment: can you please provide me the example how can i achieve this

Comment: The error indicates that your file contains an invalid character. You can write to the basex-talk mailing list and attach the file in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the RelaxNG schema is a compact one, the third argument must be `true()`.